# How to add a location for saving .svg files generated from an excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, svg

I have the following excel VBA macro which saves excel rows as .svg files in bulk. I basically scoured the internet for something that works and found this VBA Macro. I have adapted it to work for me except for selecting the folder to save. I want to define a path where the .svg files should be saved. I noticed it's saving them inside my Documents folder. I need to define the folder but I'm completely unable to figure out how this can be achieved.

```
Sub SaveRowsAsSVGs()

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook, wbNew As Excel.Workbook
Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet, wsTemp As Excel.Worksheet
Dim r As Long, c As Long
Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("worksheet")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'will overwrite existing files without asking

r = 1
Do Until Len(Trim(wsSource.Cells(r, 1).Value)) = 0
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

For c = 2 To 7
    wsTemp.Cells((c - 1) * 2 - 1, 1).Value = wsSource.Cells(r, c).Value
Next c

wsTemp.Move
Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsTemp = wbNew.Worksheets(1)
wbNew.SaveAs wsSource.Cells(r, 1).Value & ".svg", xlCSV
wbNew.Close
ThisWorkbook.Activate
r = r + 1
Loop
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`Workbook.SaveAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas) documentation:

> Parameters:
>
> *Filename*: A string that indicates the name of the file to be saved. You can include a full path; if you don't, Microsoft Excel saves the file in the current folder.

Change

```
wbNew.SaveAs wsSource.Cells(r, 1).Value & ".svg", xlCSV
```

to

```
Dim myPath as string
myPath = "\...\...\...\" <~ Your path here, ending in a backslash

wbNew.SaveAs myPath & wsSource.Cells(r, 1).Value & ".svg", xlCSV
```